# Understanding Light / Dark Mode in Tailwind

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I am just getting up to speed in Tailwind. I am trying to understand how this CSS actually works.

Here is the sample:

```
<div class="bg-white dark:bg-slate-800 rounded-lg px-6 py-8 ring-1 ring-slate-900/5 shadow-xl">
  <div>
    <span class="inline-flex items-center justify-center p-2 bg-indigo-500 rounded-md shadow-lg">
      <svg class="h-6 w-6 text-white" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor" aria-hidden="true"><!-- ... --></svg>
    </span>
  </div>
  <h3 class="text-slate-900 dark:text-white mt-5 text-base font-medium tracking-tight">Writes Upside-Down</h3>
  <p class="text-slate-500 dark:text-slate-400 mt-2 text-sm">
    The Zero Gravity Pen can be used to write in any orientation, including upside-down. It even works in outer space.
  </p>
</div>
```

Clearly, the `bg-white` class is used when the user prefers light mode, and `bg_slate-800` is used when the user prefers dark mode.

But I don't get how this is happening.  How does `dark:bg-slate-800` work?  What is the `dark:` doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I [followed the install instructions for tailwind](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation), created an HTML document containing the HTML you provided, then ran the command on the install page.

Then I looked at the resulting CSS file.

It contains:

```css
@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {
  .dark\:bg-slate-800 {
    --tw-bg-opacity: 1;
    background-color: rgb(30 41 59 / var(--tw-bg-opacity));
  }
```

`dark:` isn't doing anything special. It is just part of a class name used in a media query for [prefers-color-scheme](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/prefers-color-scheme).

Comment: I'm not sure if I agree that "dark: isn't doing anything special". Sure, in the compiled CSS it's just part of the name, but it's a special keyword that Tailwind lets you apply to any class name to make it work only when prefers-color-scheme is dark. It's similar to its [responsive design prefixes](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/responsive-design).